# Exit pop-up not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm trying to make my pop-up work **on exit**. I've followed many tutorials, used my own initiative, yet I still can't get it working. (Pretty new to jQuery so I'm sorry if it's obvious). Just wondering if anyone can identify what I'm doing wrong?

According to the console, this line is an issue: `$.magnificPopup.open({` Error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"

```js
            // Exit intent
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
  if (obj.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
  }
}

// Exit intent trigger
addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
  if (evt.toElement === null && evt.relatedTarget === null && !localStorage.getItem('exitintent_show')) {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: '#newsletter-form' //ID of inline element
      },
      type: 'inline',
      removalDelay: 500, //Delaying the removal in order to fit in the animation of the popup
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade mfp-fade-side', //The actual animation
    });
    //localStorage.setItem('exitintent_show', 'true'); // Set the flag in localStorage
  }
});
```

```css
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  > * {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        
        
<!--Delayed Popup-->
<div id="newsletter-form" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  <h2>Subscribe to my articles</h2>
  <p>I promise I won't bug you much, just a heads up for whenever I publish anything new.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`. See http://qnimate.com/exit-intent-using-javascript/

Comment: `$.magnificPopup.open({` according to the console, this is the issue. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"

Comment: OK, then the issue is not that the triggering is not working, but rather that you haven't installed that magnificPopup jQuery correctly. Can you edit your question to include the code that does that?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Magnific Popup here.

```
    <!--=================================
    modal -->
    
    <section class="white-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="modal-onexit" data-target="#myModal1"></div>
                    <div class="modal1 mfp-hide text-center" id="myModal1">
                        <div class="modal-shop white-bg">
                            @*<span class="theme-color">Winter offer for new user</span>*@
                            <h3 class="theme-color">Request for call back to know Exclusive offer</h3>
                            <form action="YOUR-ACTION" method="post">
                                <div class="row no-gutter mt-50">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-10">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" class="form-control placeholder" required autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-10">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" class="form-control placeholder" required autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-10">
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Phone*" class="form-control placeholder" required autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-10">
                                        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message*" class="form-control placeholder" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-30">
                                        <button type="submit" class="button">Get my Exclusive Offer</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <span class="theme-color mt-20 mb-20"> <a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">No Thanks, I don't want any offer! </a> </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <!--=================================
    modal -->
    
    
    
        <script>
            // Exit intent
            function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
                if (obj.addEventListener) {
                    obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
                }
                else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                    obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
                }
            }
    
            // Exit intent trigger
            addEvent(document, 'mouseleave', function (evt) {
                var $modal = $('.modal-onexit');
                if ($modal.length > 0) {
                    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
                        type: 'inline'
                    });
                    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.magnificPopup.close();
                    });
                    var elementTarget = $modal.attr('data-target');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $.magnificPopup.open({
                            items: { src: elementTarget },
                            type: "inline",
                            mainClass: "mfp-no-margins mfp-fade",
                            closeBtnInside: !0,
                            fixedContentPos: !0,
                            removalDelay: 500
                        }, 0)
                    }, 0);
                }
    
            });
    
       </script>
```